# WCF authentication on IIS7 shared hosting

Tags: wcf, wcf-security, shared-hosting

After several days of tests I find the only way I can create a WCF web service with authentication is to put a certificate in localmachine/trustedpeople cert store. The host will not do this for me. Do you know any way to enable WCF authentication without putting a cert in that store? Is there any other way to get WCF security working on shared hosting?

I have worked with a sample on codeproject that puts certs in app_data, but I haven't been able to get that to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did some very simple test on my local IIS. I have very simple service with single method. To expose the service I use this configuration:

```
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="CertificatePath" value="D:\Applications\CertificateFromFile\App_Data\ServerCert.pfx" />
    <add key="CertificatePassword" value="password" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
          <serviceCredentials>
            <userNameAuthentication userNamePasswordValidationMode="Custom" customUserNamePasswordValidatorType="CertificateFromFile.MyPasswordValidator, CertificateFromFile" />
          </serviceCredentials>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <protocolMapping>
      <clear />
      <add scheme="http" binding="wsHttpBinding" />
    </protocolMapping>
    <bindings>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding>
          <security mode="Message">
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" establishSecurityContext="false" negotiateServiceCredential="false" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true">
      <serviceActivations>
        <add service="CertificateFromFile.MyService" factory="CertificateFromFile.MyServiceHostFactory" relativeAddress="Service.svc" />
      </serviceActivations>
    </serviceHostingEnvironment>
  </system.serviceModel>
 <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

The configuration defines:

- Two custom appSettings describing path to the certificate and password.
- Single service with configuration based activation - it will have default endpoint with wsHttpBinding (defined via protocolMapping) requiring message level authentication.
- Default behaviour defining custom password validator but no service certificate!
- Service is activated on custom service host with custom ServiceHostFactory.

The whole magic of loading certificate is done in custom service host and service host factory:

```
namespace CertificateFromFile
{
    public class MyServiceHostFactory : ServiceHostFactory
    {
        protected override System.ServiceModel.ServiceHost CreateServiceHost(Type serviceType, Uri[] baseAddresses)
        {
            string path = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CertificatePath"];
            string password = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CertificatePassword"];
            return new MyServiceHost(serviceType, path, password, baseAddresses);
        }
    }

    public class MyServiceHost : ServiceHost
    {
        private readonly string _certificatePath;
        private readonly string _certificatePassword;

        public MyServiceHost(Type serviceType, string certificatePath, string certificatePassword, params Uri[] baseAddresses)
            : base(serviceType, baseAddresses)
        {
            _certificatePath = certificatePath;
            _certificatePassword = certificatePassword;
        }

        protected override void OnOpening()
        {
            base.OnOpening();

            var certificate = new X509Certificate2(_certificatePath, _certificatePassword);
            var credentials = Description.Behaviors.Find<ServiceCredentials>();
            credentials.ServiceCertificate.Certificate = certificate;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice!  I'm guessing this must have been bugging you to go through this effort.  :)

Comment: I wanted to try it myself ;) But still shared hosting is something special - there can be some other permissions problem.

Comment: Yup - and each host might do things totally different.  And I'd guess most hosts would just say, "LOL WUT?" if you called support about this...

Comment: Okay thanks for the clarity.. it is working now on shared hosting. I almost can't believe it and have to do more testing to be certain.